# Stuck on the loading screen (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

After some time of googling around and playing around, I've found out the partial solution for my loading screen not moving away and well, being stuck in the loop of infinite loading.
So, let's get straight to the point, I need the loading screen to stop and move on, so the dummy text can pop up.

The full code can be reached in this [(origin)JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqdua97o/32/).

```js
$(function(){ // this replaces document.ready
   setTimeout(function(){
    $('#loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
     $(this).remove();
    });
   }, 1500);
  });
  
                //fades out loading class
  setTimeout(function(){        
   $('#loader').fadeOut();
   $('.loading').delay(150).fadeOut('slow');
  }, 10000);
  
  //fades in the myDiv id
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#myDiv').fadeIn();
   $('.animate_bottom').delay(200).fadeIn('slow');
  }, 3000);
```

```html
<!-- hand animation parts -->
<div class="loading">
    <div class="finger finger-1">
        <div class="finger-item">
            <span></span><i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="finger finger-2">
        <div class="finger-item">
            <span></span><i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="finger finger-3">
        <div class="finger-item">
            <span></span><i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="finger finger-4">
        <div class="finger-item">
            <span></span><i></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="last-finger">
        <div class="last-finger-item"><i></i></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- main page part -->
 
<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
 <h2>Lorem ipsum!</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: `$ is not defined` - did you add jquery?

Comment: I think that might be the problem..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jqdua97o/19/

Comment: Thank you all, found the problem as pointed out (first) by @fen1x.

Comment: @Roy, I actually quite like that suggestion as well, might use it some time

Comment: nice, glad to help!

Comment: Probably because of lack of explanation of the JS code

Comment: Edited the code with as much of explanation as I could possibly think of. No need of down voting my question if you just don't understand the code. I'm bad at explaining my work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add jQuery in your project to make it works

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

just add here after "[JavaScript]"

EDIT: for the future guys looking at the answer, if you got stucked in some animations not working, check if there are any errors in the console, in this particular answer there was:

```
$ is not defined
```

so jQuery was not defined, and adding the source code make it works again!

Comment: Thanks, seems like that was the case :D , was so sure I had everything